# mysql storage in spite of sufficient memory

Tags: mysql, temp

i have one query which is causing problem and according to google it is because of insufficient temp memory.

the same query was working just fine few days back and my website got hacked and after restoring from backup i am getting this type of error however database was as usual old one.

```
         "Incorrect key file for table /tmp/#sql_xxx_x.MYI" error

          1030 Got error 28 from storage engine
```

both cases i searched and found that it is because of temp memory but how suddenly temp become prblem the same query was working just fine few days back and i checked that query using mysql explain and its output was good as it says only 144 rows are examined to give the output of 20 rows.

then  i used this command to see how much really i am having memory in temp 
and it says

```
      ddfdd@drddrr[~]#  df -h
       Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
      /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
                  3.6T   49G  3.4T   2% /
      tmpfs                 7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
     /dev/sda1             243M   86M  145M  38% /boot
     /usr/tmpDSK           4.0G  3.8G     0 100% /tmp
```

so where is the problem and how i can resolve it? 
any advice will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Double check that /tmp does not have other files using all of the space and preventing MySQL from creating an on disk tmp table.

Alternatively you can create a new tmp directory off your root slice as it has plenty of space and then change your tmpdir variable in the my.cnf to point to it. Though this is not a dynamic variable and will require a restart. Make sure to chown the directory so MySQL can write to it.